# Given a heap address, can gdb show which function allocated the heap at this address?

Tags: gdb

In windbg, we can use "!heap -p -a [address]" to show the stacktrace when the heap was allocated.

In gdb, especially for kernel debugging, there is any way to achieve the same thing in linux?

Comment: I really looked hard to find what you want but, i couldn't find any close thing to your question. I don't know how WinDBG support that feature, maybe because Windows NT specific kernel structure. Edit: I saw Igor's answer now. You must find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Windbg relies on the user-mode stack trace database provided by the kernel/ntdll. I think there is nothing similar built-in into Linux, but you can try some third-party tools, e.g. [heaptrack](http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-Linux)